# Would Cabal Stronghold count Snow-Covered Swamps?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Would [Cabal Stronghold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCabal%20Stronghold%5d) count [Snow-Covered Swamp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnow-Covered%20Swamp%5d) for making mana?

I would assume so, as Cabal Stronghold counts basic swamp cards, and Snow-Covered Swamps have both basic and swamp on the card type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, the snow-covered lands do count as basic lands.

> 205.4c Any land with the supertype “basic” is a basic land. Any land that doesn’t have this supertype is a nonbasic land, even if it has a
>   basic land type.: Cards printed in sets prior to the Eighth Edition
>   core set didn’t use the word “basic” to indicate a basic land. Cards
>   from those sets with the following names are basic lands and have
>   received errata in the Oracle card reference accordingly: Forest,
>   Island, Mountain, Plains, Swamp, Snow-Covered Forest, Snow-Covered
>   Island, Snow-Covered Mountain, Snow-Covered Plains, and **Snow-Covered
>   Swamp**.